# Get next event from a EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

My problem: When I type my postcode in this `MaskedViewGroup` field (in a big form), the 'next' `button` in android keyboard is not working. Therefore I can not move to the next field, the only way is clicking in the next field so the postcode can be loaded.

I have a `MaskedViewGroup` class, extending a `FormMaskedItemViewGroup` extending a `LinearLayout`.

How can I get the next event? Maybe I have to overwrite a method in my `MaskedViewGroup`.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **OnKeyListener** first implement if then

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode ==66)
        {
            // this is for delkey
            switch (v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.payment_screen_et_card_number_part2:

                if (et2.getText().toString().length() == 10) et1.requestFocus();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

IN inCreate()

```
  et2.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

**OR**
In ur xml

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/textView2"

android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```